# Cron Permission Denied

Tags: linux, bash, cron, sh

good day,
I have a bash script in my home directory that works properly from the command line (file structure is default media temple DV. < noted for certain permission issues) but receive this error from cron: "/home/myFile.sh: line 2: /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/techspatch/installation.sql: Permission denied" NOTICE: it's just line 2... it writes to the local server just fine.

Below is the Bash File:

```
    #!/bin/bash
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hHOST dbName> /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/techspatch/installation.sql

mysql -uadmin -pPASSWORD -hlocalhost dbName< /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/techspatch/installation.sql
```

can't chmod from bash (lol, yeah i tried). writing the file there and setting the permissions before the transfer is useless...

i have googled the heck out of this situation and this one still seems unique.... any insight is appreciated

Comment: please check with which permissions the file `installation.sql` is created when you execute the file manually and with which permissions when run from cron.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but are you trying to run this from your crontab or a different users crontab?

Comment: thanks guys, i DID have to change permissions on my .sql file. Catherine, I appreciate the check, but i was originally trying to run from the user, but have successfully set everything through root. I was bale to get this problem resolved on my end, but will leave the thread open in case anyone has a sure fire solution to all these permission issues! 

PS: writing the file there and setting the permissions before the transfer was >not< useless

Answer (score 1):

Are there any environment variables that might be significant (maybe something MySQL pays attention to - I'm not really familiar with mySQL)?  Remember that a cron job doesn't start with your environment, so you might need to define some in the bash script.